# LiveWriter Post to Blog generates SOAP Exception when post contains images

Tags: error, blog, soap

My company recently moved our wiki, blogs and internal knowledge base to a outsource SharePoint host sherweb.com. I have been using LiveWriter (2011 - 15.4.3555.308) to post my updates to the blog and it has worked great. Even when the post contains an image... all was magical.
My workflow was capture the image with SnagIt and then paste it straight into LiveWriter, do the edits and submit it.

As of last week these exact steps now generate an error. If I trace the HTTP calls with Fiddler I get two HTTP 500 errors. The first being

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.</faultstring><detail><errorstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">Parameter Url is missing or invalid.</errorstring><errorcode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">0x82000001</errorcode></detail></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Followed by

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.</faultstring><detail><errorstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">The list item was saved, but attachments could not be saved because the attachments feature is currently unavailable for this list.</errorstring><errorcode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">0x81020055</errorcode></detail></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I know nothing about SharePoint but the second error seems quite helpful. The first could just be an artifact of the API but since I don't have a working trace to compare with I'm a bit stuck.

> The list item was saved, but attachments could not be saved because
>   the attachments feature is currently unavailable for this list.

I've contacted our SharePoint provider but it is proving difficult to get any positive results. What was once working is now broken.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much clicking around in the SharePoint designer, I noticed the option marked *Enable Attachments* was unticked. Upon ticking this option I received and error stating the "attachments folder already exists" (and in fact the attachments feature worked as expected via the web interface).

So on a hunch I made a backup of the Attachments folder on the SharePoint share by renaming it to **_Attachments**. Then I ticked the *Enable Attachments* option again. SharePoint re-created the **Attachments** directory and posting via LiveWriter worked again!
Also of interest is the check mark disappeared from the check box again.

It would seem something happened to the directory to prevent saving files into it. Probably broken NTFS permissions or similar.